# Why does not catkin_make work?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two versions of ***src*** file in the package under the workspace. I ran one and named the other ***src2*** (CmakeList.txt compiles the source file in ***src*** directory). Then I want to run the other version files, so ***src*** is renamed to ***src1*** and ***src2*** is renamed to ***src***, and I ran `catkin_make` in the workspace, but there is no new file generated and when I start the node, it' s still the old one.
It's so weird. Can someone explain it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331239/why-does-not-catkin_make-work?/) by [Liulong Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/39506/liulong-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have two versions of src file in the
> package under the workspace

I understand it as both your `src` folder contains files with the same names and same `CMakeList` but only some lines of code differs between the two.
That being said when you run `catkin_make` after swapping your folders `catkin` doesn't notice any change in your files (I don't really know how, probably `CMake` related, but if someone can enlighten me on this part) so if nothing has changed `catkin` won't rebuild everything as usual.

To avoid that you have two options :

1. Delete the `build` and `devel` folder each time you change the `src` folder
2. Change a little thing in a file so that catkin notice a change and rebuild the package

The best option is the first one but I would recommend for that kind of things to use a version-control tool such as `GIT` or `SVN`.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-08-21**:
I think make will only rebuild a file if the source has a more recent timestamp than the last time it was built, so by renaming the same files I don't think it will pickup the change because it will still have it's original timestamp. Not 100% sure on this, but try adding a single space to update the timestamp and try it again.